# Finding a CFD paper with extra degree of freedom variable in mass conservation

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, reference-request

I am trying to find a paper that I saw about a year ago. I am not sure of the actual date of the paper.

I believe it was a finite difference CFD paper. The interesting part of the paper was the addition of a single degree of freedom variable to all of the mass conservation equations. This residual mass conservation variable was included to stabilize the iteration of their scheme.

Alternatively, I would be interested in suggestions on handling convergence issues that may be caused by replacing one of the mass conservation equations with a pressure average along the outlet of the fluid domain.

I am also considering switching to the pressure Poisson equations with a projection method to be selected later.

Comment: pressure relaxation schemes do this for (compressible) multiphase flows. check out the “six equation model”

Comment: Would it ever make sense to do it in a single fluid phase flow? I am considering it to be able to add a DOF that lets me assign an average outlet pressure without switching from continuity solving to pressure Poisson equation and without leaving out a conservation equation.

Comment: Don’t think so. Sounds like I misread some details of your question

Comment: No worries, thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: You say “all the” mass conservation equations but then claim single phase flow. I guess that tripped me up. Which is it?

Comment: By "all" i meant at each cell centered node in the domain a single mass conservation equation is solved, except at one node on the outlet that is replaced with an average of pressure over the outlet currently.